# how device gallery show large images?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-image, image-gallery

Whenever I try to show large size(1 MB) bitmap in imageview, system throw OutOfMemory exception.

If I place 7-8 MB image, gallery can easily show that image.

Just want to know How device default gallery is able to show large image in easy way?

1. Which mechanism is used by device gallery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage set of images in memory cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112237/how-to-manage-set-of-images-in-memory-cache)

Comment: @Selvin: This is totally different question. FYI if u know the answer, why don't u give a answer for that question?

Comment: no, it just the same question, as "fartillion" other question here on SO which has one answer http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, they subsample the image. A 1MB PNG or JPEG file will be much higher resolution than the screen, and so it is wasteful to load the whole image in. Subsampling allows you to load the image in much closer to the actual size of the `ImageView` you will use, allowing it to fit in memory better. A simple approach to subsampling involves using `inSampleSize` on `BitmapFactory.Options`; [Dave Morrissey's `SubsamplingScaleImageView`](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) offers pinch-to-zoom and such while peforming subsampling (note: I have not tried this component, as I just ran across it a minute ago).

Comment: Thnx for immediate response. 
Is it use BitmapRegionDecoder to show large Bitmap? Is there any contact no. of ur, so i can contact u anytime directly.

I m really a BIG fan of u.

Comment: @user3740000: Yes, if you know the region you want. It too supports subsampling via `inSampleSize` on the `BitmapFactory.Options` you supply to `decodeRegion()`.

Comment: Do u have specific idea What approach to be used for cache and show 8 MB image with providing Pinch-Zoom. 

Any specific link or demo which do this type of thing efficiently?

Comment: @user3740000: That is all too broad for a Stack Overflow answer, let alone a comment. I already provided a link in my answer that covers your pinch-to-zoom scenario.

Comment: Thnx Commonsware, I gone through the code and test app, its an amazing. Its provide similar functionality like device default gallery. I can't expect more than this.